# Typescript Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have referred other answers but could not solve my problem

```
console.log(`home.ts : ${result} : ${typeof result},${typeof this.points}`);
```

returns

```
home.ts : 50 : number,number
```

but this line

```
 this.points = result;
```

throws the following error:

> Typescript Error: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.

full function

```
getdefaultscore(){
  this.authService.getdefaultscore().then(
    (result)=>{
      console.log(`home.ts : ${result} : ${typeof result},${typeof this.points}`);
      this.points = result;
    },
    (err)=>{
      this.authService.alertnointernetconnection();
    }
  )
}
```

`this.points` is defined as number.

definition of getdefaultscore()

```
  getdefaultscore(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
        this.http.post('mysite.com/ionuserpoint.php',JSON.stringify({defaultpoints:true}),headers)
        .subscribe(
            (res) =>{
                let data = res.json();
                data = parseFloat(data);
                alert(`defaults points : ${data}`);
                resolve(data);
            },
            (err) =>{
              reject(err);
            }
        );
    });
  }
```

I remove http://www before mysite.com because stackoverflow throws some error.

Comment: And what is a definition of `getdefaultscore()` ?

Comment: How do you declare this.points? `points: number` ?

Comment: are you using points: number; or points = number

Comment: @Fetra R yes bro

Comment: @amyogiji I am using points:number

Comment: @Aleksey L. bro but it returns number and typeof it also number

Comment: @vSugumar I see the results at runtime. But what is a definition of return type of `this.authService.getdefaultscore()`? It must be `Promise<OfSomething>` I believe

Comment: @Aleksey I updated my question, you can now see the definition of getdefaultscore

Comment: @vSugumar You're welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th problem is in `getdefaultscore` which returns a `Promise<{}>` ideally you should change it to return a `Promise<number>`. Since you do not provide the code for `getdefaultscore` it is difficult to say what change you should make there. To solve the problem on the caller side you can manually type the result :

```
declare function getdefaultscore(): Promise<{}>; // Dummy declaration 
var points : number;
function x() {
  getdefaultscore().then((result: number)=>{
    points = result;
  },
  (err)=>{
  })
}
```

Another version you can consider in Typescript is using async/await to simplify your `Promise` code:

```
async function x2() {
  try {
    points = <number>await getdefaultscore()
  } catch (ex) {

  }
}
```

Edit: You added the `getdefaultscore` after the original answer. Since you create the promis manually, you just need to type it to `Promise<number>`.

Comment: I tried parseFloat(resolve) but it throwed a different error

Comment: Edited the answer, you just need to type the promise to number

Comment: That is assuming the returned json is just a single number, but that is a different problem, if data is a more complex object `pareseFloat` will fail in other ways